# ¿Es posible pasar con PHP via GET / POST un token con AJAX y json sin hacer un echo?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo un archivo llamado token.php que genera un token:

**token.php**

```
echo json_encode(Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
```

Y tengo un archivo que coge ese token con AJAX y ejecuta códigos posteriores:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "token",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(".inputDisabled").show();
        ...
```

Todo funciona bien, pero si un visitante de mi página va a `mipagina.com/token` verá el token. Necesito esconderlo de alguna forma, pero sin que afecte al GET.

¿Es esto posible y cómo he de hacerlo? Si no es posible, ¿me podríais dar una solución alternativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea es conocer cual fue la forma de ingreso al archivo, si fue por medio de ajax o copiando la url en el browser, lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es enviar una variable con la cual identifiques ese ingreso, así:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "token",
    type: "GET",
    data: {check: true},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(".inputDisabled").show();
        ...
```

Y en **check.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['check']) && $_GET['check'] == true){
    echo json_encode(Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
}
```

Así estarías limitando a que se imprima el token únicamente cuando el origen es ajax.

Por seguridad yo cambiaría la petición de `GET` a `POST`

Comment: Muchas gracias @CamiloVasquez voy a implementar tu sugerencia y te dejo saber

Answer (score 2):

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

1) en tu archivo php crea una variable SESION, de la siguiente manera:
  1.a) escribe `session_start();` al inicio de tu codigo php. (ejemplo: [click aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp))

1.b) Crea una variable de tipo sesión y dale algún valor para validarla, para que únicamente cuando  se ingrese a esa página, esta se encargue de crear la variable y asignarle valor. Ejemplo: `$_SESSION["accesotoken"] = "si";`

2) en tu archivo del token.php siempre agregas el `session_start();` y validas:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["accesotoken"]) && $_SESSION["accesotoken"] == si){
echo json_encode(Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
```

}

y con eso ya tendrías algo seguro ese archivo. Ahora, me opongo un poco en poner la variable de acceso y el valor que permita el acceso dentro del código JavaScript, ya que es un tanto vulnerable y se podría acceder a tu archivo de manera fácil. Pero de la manera que te expongo, todo se maneja desde el propio PHP y por ende, del lado del servidor.

Comment: Hola MRH, en la manera en que exhibes tu solución, si se llegase a copiar en la url la ruta específica del archivo SIEMPRE se va a ejecutar session_start(); por ende siempre van a existir las variables de sesión creadas, saludos !